# What is the most efficient way to convert a form to a multi-page form?

Tags: javascript, forms, pagination, frontend, multipage

I'm working with wordpress.org and have a form created by GeoDirectory plugin. This form has over 20 input fields and looks very big on the page. The plugin doesn't support multi-page functionality so I'm trying to figure this out on front-end.

What I'm trying to figure out is what is the best way to convert the form(all elements visible) to a multi-page form (pagination). It has been suggested to me to use something like Bootstrap Accordion element but I'm skeptical about manipulating the initial form.

What I have though of doing is to create another form which won't have any form submit and take those values and place them in the initial (hidden) form. But I'm also unsure if this is going to work. Let me know for other solutions and tips. My main concern is performance and data loss.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

What I have done so far is to collect the form in a JavaScript array. Then I created a 2d array to hold a section and for each section there is a secondary array that holds form input fields. The 2D array looks like this:

```
let section1 = [input1,input2,input3];
....
let array = [section1, section2, section3];
```

I managed to create the visual representation of a multipage form which looks like this:
[image: screen shot 1]

I'm about to create the functionality for the next / previous buttons and I wanted to ask first if the above solution is applicable. Please let me know if you have any comments that would improve the above solution.

Comment: _"but I'm skeptical about manipulating the initial form"_ - why? If the plugin offers any possibility to do that (theming for the form, or hooks to manipulate its HTML structure), that would IMHO be much preferable, to trying to clone the form on the frontend, and then trying to move data from one to the other. What does the structure of the form you got, look like? Does the plugin allow you to use any "grouping" elements to wrap a number of form fields into a container of their own, anything like that ...?

Comment: Hi @CBroe I did not create a new form and transfer data. I'm working with the initial form and just relocating parts of the form in different sections of my page. It looks to be working okay even if elements are hidden the values still exists. The way the plugin works is that I define the fields I want to use in WP-Dashboard and then use a shortcode (e.g. [gd-add-listing-event-form]) to display the form. On page load the shortcode dumps a <form> in the page (just like any other regular form). Plugin does not allow grouping or wraping in back-end. so it has to be done either via php or js

Comment: _"It looks to be working okay even if elements are hidden the values still exists."_ - yes, as long as the input fields are properly contained within the form element in the DOM, it does not matter if they are hidden via `display: none` or something. (If client-side form validation using the `required` or `pattern` attribute is in play though, this can become problematic - the browser would still consider fields that are not currently shown, invalid. But the user has little chance to the see corresponding error message then.)

Comment: If you are looking into Bootstrap for the UI, then I would suggest using Tabs rather than Accordions though. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior